# How-to; Echo entire "goto" section

Tags: variables, batch-file, goto

I am working on a text based adventure game for a few friends and I to work through in batch. I'd like to make the option to have an entire section of variables echoed when wanted. Below is the entry code. The first section, Variables, is not an accessed section, but creates variables prior to the game starting. The second section, stats, provides these variables echoed.

```
@ECHO OFF
::Variables
set Name=Und
set Gender=Und
set Age=Und
set Gold=0
set Hunger=Satisfied
set Illness=None
set Wounds=None
set CHP=10
set MHP=10
set CMP=0
set MMP=0
goto Start
::Stats 
:Stats
cls
echo    Name: %Name%
echo  Gender: %Gender%
echo     Age: %Age%
echo    Gold: 0
echo.
echo Health
echo  Hunger: %Hunger%
echo Illness: %Illness%
echo  Wounds: %Wounds%
echo.
echo Stats
echo      HP: %CHP%/%MHP%
echo      MP: %CMP%/%MMP%
```

My current solution to this issue is using

```
set /p "situation"= :
if "%situation%"=="1" goto nextpart
if "%situation%"=="2" goto nextpart
if "%situation%"=="3" goto nextpart
if "%situation%"=="Stats" goto Stats.
```

The issue with this method, however, is that once in stats, I have no way to jump to the previous section. It would require me making an exit gateway to every possible section I've created. So the question:
Can I have a series of variables echoed without leaving the current section?

Comment: Why in the name of the gods are you don't this in batch? It can't be because you're a batch guru and just want to show off, or you wouldn't be here. What other plausible reason is there? o.O Get a real language.

Comment: Batch is the only language I have any amount of experience with, it's easy to work with using simple commands, can easily be edited on any computer/device, and so far works for my needs. I have no practice with any other language, but if you could recommend one I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'd recommend Lua. It's small, simple, and you can distribute the interpreter for it without requiring an install. I'll show how what you've written so far can be written in Lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Call:stats` in place of `goto:stats`. 
Like this it will comme back in the current section

Edit :

```
@echo off
set $var=1000

call:aff
echo done   
exit/b

:aff
echo %$var%
```

Comment: Ah, didn't even think to save the variables to another bat file for call. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to save it to another bat file. You can use `call:stats` in your bat itself. Check the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You can get Lua [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2.3/Executables/lua-5.2.3_Win32_bin.zip/download)

There's a somewhat out of date version of the Lua book [here.](http://scite-ru.googlecode.com/files/Programming%20in%20Lua%202ed.pdf)

Here's an example of how you could write this in Lua:

```
-- create a bunch of variables
Name = nil
Gender = nil
Age = nil
Gold = 0
Hunger = 'Satisfied'
Illness = 'None'
Wounds = 'None'
CHP = 10
MHP = 10
CMP = 0
MMP = 0

-- create a routine whose job it is to print the variables
function stats()
    print('  Name: ' .. Name     )
    print('Gender: ' .. Gender   )
    print('   Age: ' .. Age      )
    print('  Gold: ' .. Gold     )
    print('Health'               )
    print(' Hunger: ' .. Hunger  )
    print('Illness: ' .. Illness )
    print(' Wounds: ' .. Wounds  )
    print(''                     )
    print('Stats'                )
    print('     HP: ' .. CHP .. '/' .. MHP )
    print('     MP: ' .. CMP .. '/' .. MMP )
end

-- call the routine
stats()
```

This appears more verbose that your BAT code, but once your game logic starts to get complicated, using a real programming language will make it much easier *and* more rewarding.

Comment: Thanks. I'll begin the conversion. Luckily I'm only about 300 lines in. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to arrange a save/restore regime in batch is to reserve a prefix for the variables to be saved/restored. For instance, if you were to reserve `$` for the variables of interest, then

```
set $>savefile
```

is all you'd need to save all of the `$` variables to a file and

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (savefile) do set %%a
```

would restore them.